# Why isn't this program executing?

Tags: java

I was writing a main class for my project where i get the current working directory and pass it on to my menu class (I need my directory because I am using PNGs in my project and I am including this so that I could change the location of my files and this would work on other computers too).

```
private static Menu m;
public static void main(String args[]){
    m = new Menu(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
}
```

So far so good and its working perfectly fine in my IDE. But I was converting this project to a jar file and when I execute it, it just doesn't do anything. So my question is: what is wrong with this code? Why isn't it executing?

Comment: "*But I was converting this project to a jar file and when I execute it, it just doesn´t do anything*" - How did you convert it to a jar? How did you execute it?

Comment: There´s an option in this IDE for creating a Jar File out of the project and it gives me a few options (for example what class to use for main class) and then i just double clicked the finished jar file... should i try to execute via cmd?

Comment: You should read up on what it means to create a jar, try to understand what your IDE does and read up on how to execute jar files. You most probably have to start your jar from command line, yes.

Comment: Which IDE? You may need to export as a runnable jar, opposed to just a jar

Comment: I´m using BlueJ (for Students and yeah i should probably switch to netbeans or maybe eclipse)

Comment: When I´m executing it via command line it throws a few exeptions that my Menu class cannot be found...

Comment: Make and show a [mcve]. We don't see a class (public?), nor import statements - what menu is it? java.awt.Menu? Your own creation? JavaFX? com.michellin.fr.Menu?

Comment: Got it to work :) thx for the help guys

Comment: Please understand this hyperbole analogy as a means to help you ask better questions in the future: "So in my garage the car works, but when I put it on the street it won't start. Here's a photo of my car keys."

Comment: (We don't use [solved] devices in titles here to mark a question as answered. If you can post the answer in an answer proper, that is the best way to do it. Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

I´m sorry for my stupid way of asking this question... If you are interested: The problem was that my classes didn´t share the same package, so the class i was showing an excerpt of didnt knew the class which i was trying to initiate...